# PHP MySQL connecting error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question that is really bothering my understanding of working with php and MySQL. The problem is when i try to connect to my online DB. 
If I Write my code like this:

```
 define('DB_NAME', 'name');
 define('DB_USER', 'user');
 define('DB_PASS', 'pass!');
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

I connect with no problems. Great, that works!
But, when i want to connect like this:

```
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "user";
 $password = "pass";
 $dbname = "name";
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

I get this error:  "Access denied for user..."

Can somebody please help me with this silly problem?

Comment: Maybe that you are using two different passwords?

Comment: nope, that is just a type error here ;)

Comment: There are no other variables on the page called $servername, $username, $password or $dbname?

The connection is not trying to be established within a function?

Comment: No, there are not. I have tried both, in a function and out of it

Comment: Please post the actual code you use in both cases to be able to compare both variants.

Comment: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} `


What appears?

Try putting details directly into `$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pw", "correctdatabasename");`

Comment: @PhilipThomson don't paste the code in comments do that in your answer

Comment: Tried putting them directly in as well; same error

Comment: check your password..first you define  `define('DB_PASS', 'pass!')` that execute successfully.and second script you define  `$password = "pass"`.

Comment: @PhilipThomson your passwords are not the same on the scripts

Comment: The password is actually the same in both cases in the online files...

Comment: thats not what your code is showing

Comment: it is, just replaced the passwords and username and db name

Comment: You need to report the errors, so that you can know why are you getting them, that code you have up there won't tell you why unless you check for em

Comment: @MohammadAnini please don't change the code in questions. Check out the Help Center guidelines on what edits are OK and what edits are not OK.

Comment: @TylerH if you check the comments above you will know why I changed the code!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for both options

```
<?php

//Creates static credentials
define('DB_NAME', 'data');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');


//Creates connection to the database
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

//Checks for connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

//If there are no connection, error
if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect' . mysqli_error());
}

//Select the 'data' database
$con->select_db(DB_NAME);

//Checks if database 'data' has been selected
if (mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME)) {
        echo "Database exists <br>";
} else {
        echo "Database does not exist";
    }

    if($con){

        echo "connection succss";
    }

?>
```

option 2

```
<?php

    $servername="localhost";
    $username ="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{

    echo "connected";
}
?>
```

Those are my codes, and also yours is working fine, might be a problem, with your username/password

Comment: use the code I did then tell me the error it prints

Comment: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'bogat584_tadej'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: does user `bogat584_tadej` have all the privileges? what happen when you try to connect using `root` with no password?

Comment: Yes, he has all privilages

Comment: then the problem is with ur password, please test the script by connecting with root with no password

Comment: In that case i get this error: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'bogat584_bogat584'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I just set the password and now it WORKS!!! Can you please explain why this happened?

Comment: But previously when i used a different user, the pass was the same in both cases

Answer (score -1):

This happens some time because you have changed user name and password of data base or you can try make your user as root and password empty.

Comment: But i have root privilages for this user

Comment: This is just a wide shot given without knowing the actual issue.

Comment: Yes, it works for the first one, that is why i do not understand

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$mysql_host     = 'localhost';
$mysql_user     = 'user';
$mysql_password = 'pass';
$mysql_database = 'localhost';
$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
@mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
```

Also check the privelges for that user.

Comment: I do not get any error in this case... Why is that?

Comment: we using `mysqli_*` not mysql_* mysql is no longer supported, and suppressing errors with `@` does not do you any favours